# How to count cookies using angularjs

Tags: javascript, angularjs, cookies

I am doing small application using angular js, In that, I have maintaining product details in cart using ngcookies, As soon as the product was added in cart how to count all product id from cookies. I have attach my code below. Is there possible to count value from cookies using angularjs

Html:

```
<a href="javascript:void(0);" class="addtocart_class btn btn-default" ng-click="WriteCookie(album.trackId)">Add to cart</a>
```

Controller:

```
 $scope.basketlist = [];    
 $scope.count = $scope.$cookies.get('basketlist').length;
 $scope.WriteCookie = function (index) {
    if($scope.basketlist.length === 0){
        //console.log("Hello");
        if(typeof($cookies.get('basketlist')) !== "undefined"){
            //console.log("I am getting");
            $scope.basketlist.push($cookies.get('basketlist'));
        }

    }else{
        $scope.basketlist.push(index);
    }

    //console.log($scope.basketlist);
    $scope.count = $scope.basketlist.length;
    $cookies.put("basketlist", $scope.basketlist);

    //console.log($cookies.get('basketlist')); 

};
```

As soon as value was added in cookies, i want to increase my cart count, For that i used above code, I dint get output.

Comment: Check if value is added in the $scope.basketlist array

Comment: Thanks for your replies, I used split by commas and get that lenght for that total count.

Answer (score 0):

$cookies.get return a string

You can do **JSON.stringify** and **JSON.parse** by yourself.

Or you can just use **$cookies.getObject** to get the deserialized value of given cookie key.

And there is no **$scope.$cookies**

https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ngCookies/service/$cookies